# Latex Figures side-by-side in AR document class

Tags: latex, tex

I am currently working on formatting an article for publication in Annual Reviews journal. They provide the class file that suppose to make the process easier.
The file could be downloaded here: https://www.annualreviews.org/pb-assets/Authors%20Assets/AR-Style1-1653591280420.zip

Here is the MRE:

```
\documentclass{ar-1col-S2O}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

% Document starts
\begin{document}

%Example of a Figure
\section{ELEMENTS\ OF\ THE\ MANUSCRIPT} 
\subsection{Figures}Figures should be cited in the main text in chronological order. This is dummy text with a citation to the first figure (\textbf{Figure \ref{fig:sub_a}}). Citations to \textbf{Figure \ref{fig:sub}} (and other figures) will be bold. 

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[Figure A]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:sub_a}}\quad
    \subfloat[Figure A]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig:sub_b}}
    \caption{Combined figure}\label{fig:sub}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me this:
[image]

And I need it to look like this (side-by-side with bold panel marker in the corner):
[image: Target]

Any help or suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Please add a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{ar-1col-S2O}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

% Document starts
\begin{document}

%Example of a Figure
\section{ELEMENTS\ OF\ THE\ MANUSCRIPT} 
\subsection{Figures}Figures should be cited in the main text in chronological order. This is dummy text with a citation to the first figure (\textbf{Figure \ref{fig:sub_a}}). Citations to \textbf{Figure \ref{fig:sub}} (and other figures) will be bold. 

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    \subfloat[Figure A]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:sub_a}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill    
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    \subfloat[Figure A]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig:sub_b}}
\end{minipage}
    \caption{Combined figure}\label{fig:sub}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is important to preserve the default format for figure capture. I tried subcaption -> messes up the caption format; I tried minipage -> messes up in-text figure references. I tried making tabular inside figure -> same result as subfig.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you also be able to provide any guidance on how to transform sub-figure captions to the same format as in the screenshot? (bold letter in top left corner)

Comment: @ilyywa This would have been possible with the subcaption package - I'm not aware of a solution for subfig